# Adding a Blank row after a group by in Sql

Tags: sql, winforms

i have a set of values in my database table, i will want to add a blank row after a group of data.

here is what i have done;

```
SELECT election AS Election, candidate AS Candidate, COUNT(candidate) AS [Result Count]
FROM result2
GROUP BY candidate, election
```

my result is;

```
Election   | candidate   |  Result Count
President  | Name One | 5
president | Second Name | 2
Secretary | Third Name | 4
Secretary | Fourth Name | 2
```

please i will like to add a blank row after each group of elections.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you're using .Net, I'd probably handle this in the application.  It's not really what the database is intended for.  If you can't change the application, you'll probably need to use a `union` with conditional ordering depending on your database...

Comment: ok, thank you.please how do i achieve this using datagrid view

Answer (score 0):

I did this exercise:

```
select tt.[Election],tt.[candidate],case tt.[Result Count] when 0 then null else tt.[Result Count] end as [Result Count]
from
(SELECT [Election],[candidate],seq as seq,[Result Count]
FROM
(
select t.[Election],t.[candidate], ROW_NUMBER()  OVER ( ORDER BY result2.id) as seq, '' AS [Result Count] from result2
cross apply ( select '' as [Election],'' as [candidate], null as [Result Count]) T
) T
UNION 
select result2.[Election],result2.[candidate], ROW_NUMBER()  OVER ( ORDER BY result2.id) as seq, COUNT(result2.candidate) AS [Result Count] 
from result2
group by result2.[Election],result2.[candidate],result2.ID

) tt
ORDER BY tt.seq,tt.Election desc
```

return null in case of [Result Count] = 0 in blank row

using Cross apply you can generate blank row